# How to remove navigationview selection indicator place

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml, navigationview

Can someone suggest how to remove selection indicator from NavigationView of UWP.

Below style remove indicator but still shows empty space at the beginning of item as shown on attached screenshot.

`<SolidColorBrush x:Key="NavigationViewSelectionIndicatorForeground" Color="Transparent" />`

[image: NavigationView Highlighted Space]

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to remove navigationview selection indicator place

Derive from `NavigationViewItemPresenter` style you could find `IconBox` contain a default margin [`NavigationViewItemIconBoxMargin`](https://github.com/unoplatform/uno/blob/master/src/Uno.UI/UI/Xaml/Controls/NavigationView/NavigationView_rs5_themeresources.xaml#L8) left side is 10 px. if you want to remove
indicator place, please update 10 to 0 like the following.

```
<Thickness x:Key="NavigationViewItemIconBoxMargin">0,12,16,12</Thickness>
```

And please note if you want above `Thickness` could work, you also need to add `NavigationViewItemPresenter` and `NavigationViewItem` style in the page resource like this [line](https://github.com/ZhuMingHao/NavigationViewItemsTest/blob/master/NavigationViewItemsTest/MainPage.xaml#L27).

Update for 16299

```
<Style TargetType="NavigationViewItem">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource NavigationViewItemForeground}" />
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{ThemeResource NavigationViewItemBackground}" />
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource NavigationViewItemBorderBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="{StaticResource NavigationViewItemBorderThickness}" />
    <Setter Property="UseSystemFocusVisuals" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="NavigationViewItem">
                <Grid
                    x:Name="LayoutRoot"
                    Height="40"
                    Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                    Control.IsTemplateFocusTarget="True">
                    <!--  Wrap SelectionIndicator in a grid so that its offset is 0,0 - this enables the offset animation.  -->
                    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center">

                        <Rectangle
                            x:Name="SelectionIndicator"
                            Width="6"
                            Height="24"
                            Fill="{ThemeResource NavigationViewSelectionIndicatorForeground}"
                            Opacity="0.0" />
                    </Grid>

                    <Border
                        x:Name="RevealBorder"
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" />

                    <Grid Height="40" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition x:Name="IconColumn" Width="48" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <Viewbox
                            x:Name="IconBox"
                            Margin="-10,12,16,12"
                            Child="{TemplateBinding Icon}" />

                        <ContentPresenter
                            x:Name="ContentPresenter"
                            Grid.Column="1"
                            Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                            HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                            VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                            Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                            ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
                            ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}" />
                    </Grid>

                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="PointerStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />

                            <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Target="LayoutRoot.(RevealBrush.State)" Value="PointerOver" />
                                    <Setter Target="LayoutRoot.Background" Value="{ThemeResource NavigationViewItemBackgroundPointerOver}" />
                                    <Setter Target="RevealBorder.BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource NavigationViewItemBorderBrushPointerOver}" />
                                    <Setter Target="ContentPresenter.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource NavigationViewItemForegroundPointerOver}" />
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>

                            <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Target="LayoutRoot.(RevealBrush.State)" Value="Pressed" />
                                    <Setter Target="LayoutRoot.Background" Value="{ThemeResource NavigationViewItemBackgroundPressed}" />
                                    <Setter Target="RevealBorder.BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource NavigationViewItemBorderBrushPressed}" />
                                    <Setter Target="ContentPresenter.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource NavigationViewItemForegroundPressed}" />
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>

                            <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Target="LayoutRoot.Background" Value="{ThemeResource NavigationViewItemBackgroundSelected}" />
                                    <Setter Target="RevealBorder.BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource NavigationViewItemBorderBrushSelected}" />
                                    <Setter Target="ContentPresenter.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource NavigationViewItemForegroundSelected}" />
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>

                            <VisualState x:Name="PointerOverSelected">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Target="LayoutRoot.(RevealBrush.State)" Value="PointerOver" />
                                    <Setter Target="LayoutRoot.Background" Value="{ThemeResource NavigationViewItemBackgroundSelectedPointerOver}" />
                                    <Setter Target="RevealBorder.BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource NavigationViewItemBorderBrushSelectedPointerOver}" />
                                    <Setter Target="ContentPresenter.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource NavigationViewItemForegroundSelectedPointerOver}" />
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>

                            <VisualState x:Name="PressedSelected">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Target="LayoutRoot.(RevealBrush.State)" Value="Pressed" />
                                    <Setter Target="LayoutRoot.Background" Value="{ThemeResource NavigationViewItemBackgroundSelectedPressed}" />
                                    <Setter Target="RevealBorder.BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource NavigationViewItemBorderBrushSelectedPressed}" />
                                    <Setter Target="ContentPresenter.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource NavigationViewItemForegroundSelectedPressed}" />
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>

                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="DisabledStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Enabled" />

                            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Target="LayoutRoot.Opacity" Value="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDisabledThemeOpacity}" />
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>

                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="PaneStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="NotClosedCompact" />
                            <VisualState x:Name="ClosedCompact">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Target="RevealBorder.HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left" />
                                    <Setter Target="RevealBorder.Width" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=CompactPaneLength}" />
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>

                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="IconStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="IconVisible" />
                            <VisualState x:Name="IconCollapsed">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Target="IconBox.Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                                    <Setter Target="IconColumn.Width" Value="16" />
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>

                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: Seems like this class doesn't support in my existing project. Throwing error "NavigationViewItemPresenter is not supported in a Windows Universal project".

Comment: Please share your app's target version and min version.

Comment: Sure. Min & Target: Windows 10 Fall Creators Update (10.0; Build 16299)

Comment: Yep, the style is deferent between 16299 and 1909, if your target version is 16299, you just need to edit  `IconBox` as `Margin="-10,12,16,12"`. for more please refer above update part.

Comment: Sure. Thanks a lot. :)